# How to locate the owner of a 5' styrofoam wing found in a field?

Tags: aircraft-registration

I found a 4-5' styrofoam wing in eastern Montana in a field. It has what looks like a registration number on it. How can I trace that number to try to return it?

Comment: Any possibility of getting a photo and adding it here?

Comment: Pure styrofoam, or styrofoam core with something else around? Can you please be more detailed?

Comment: If it's from an R/C plane, which seems likely, there's a chance it could have an Academy of Model Aeronautics (AMA) member number on it somewhere.

Answer (score 13):

If it has a US registration number on it (N followed by 1-5 numbers or letters) [you can search the FAA registration database](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/nnum_inquiry.aspx) to find out what aircraft has that particular registration number, and who owns it.
In the case of a 4-5 foot styrofoam wing this would likely only be useful if the aircraft in question was a registered UAV.

Some common sense needs to prevail here: Model aircraft often have an N number painted on them for decorative reasons, so if you look up N12345 and it says "That belongs to a Piper Cub" you can safely assume this wing *does not* belong to that particular real-world aircraft (as the Cub's wings are not made from styrofoam, and are more than 5 feet long).